# Update the cache when dataset is updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a data set storing all continents with their respective countries. I am caching the data table:

```
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
string cacheKey = "CoverageDataTable";
object cacheItem = Cache[cacheKey] as DataTable;
if (cacheItem == null)
{
    dset = (DataSet)_obj.GetAllContinent();
    cacheItem = dset.Tables[0];
    Cache.Insert(cacheKey, cacheItem, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromHours(5), CacheItemPriority.High, null);
 }
```

Now I want that if there is any change in the data table, fresh data should be fetched from the database. How can I do this?

Comment: How about creating Caching Dependency on Cached Items in your Dataset and as soon as there is change fetch the data from Database..

Comment: @AvkashChauhan How can I detect that change. Can you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 4):

Dependent on your SQL Database version you may be able to use SqlCacheDependency.

Very briefly in your web.config

```
<caching>
        <sqlCacheDependency pollTime="10000" enabled="true" >
            <databases>
                <add connectionStringName="ConnectionString" name="Coverage"/>
            </databases>
        </sqlCacheDependency>
    </caching>
```

Then in the code

```
private void BindData()
{
    // if null then fetch from the database
    if (Cache["CoverageDataTable"] == null)
    {
        // Create the cache dependency
        SqlCacheDependency dep = new SqlCacheDependency("Coverage", CoverageDataTable");
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
                                        "ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC " +
                                               "FROM CoverageDataTable", myConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);

        // put in the cache object
        Cache.Insert("CoverageDataTable", ds, dep);
    }

    gvCoverageDataTable.DataSource = Cache["CoverageDataTable"] as DataSet;
    gvCoverageDataTable.DataBind();
}
```

Some background can be found here: [Caching in ASP.NET with the SqlCacheDependency Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx)

Comment: By the way, don't forget a lock implementation in order to avoid subsequent requests.